# How to prevent user to access admin page

Tags: php, html, session

I have some pages and the user is stored in a session variable. But for the user it is possible to access every page.

[image: creation of variable session]

[image: select the table from the data base]

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM `pannes` WHERE `pannes`.`idDirecteur` = (
        select `idDirecteur` from `directeurs` where `directeurs`.`nomDirecteur` = '".$userName."'
    ) order by `pannes`.`date` desc,`pannes`.`heur` desc limit $page1,14 "; 
$query = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: In the future (or maybe even editing this) please add code as text using code blocks instead of adding images.

Comment: A simple fix could be to just add the user role to the users session and check that on the admin pages. `if (!isset($_SESSION['user']) || $_SESSION['user']['role'] !== 'admin') { /* redirect to login/frontpage/401 permission denied/somewhere */}`

Answer (score 1):

You can create one session for each user and check that session on each page:

Page 1:

```
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['user1'])) die('You Dont Have Access'); ?>
```

Page 2:

```
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['user2'])) die('You Dont Have Access'); ?>
```

Page 3:

```
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['user3'])) die('You Dont Have Access'); ?>
```

And in login page define different session for each user type.